# number of rows depending on user input

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create number of rows that I can type into, depending on user input.

So it asks me for a number of rows, max 100, and when I type 12, I want to have 12 rows created and I want to type into each of them but each row can have min 1 and max 100 characters of English alphabet.

Afterwards I need to do something with all of the data typed into those rows, it's like a form... but I will do that later, here is my code, please help

PS, it shows me error in VOID line....

```
 #include <iostream>

void riadkov (int arg[], int dlzka_r){
      char dlzka_r[100];
      riadkov(ulohy, dlzka_r);

int main(){
using namespace std;

int ulohy;

     cout << "zadaj pocet uloh: ";
     cin >> ulohy;
     if (ulohy >= 1 && ulohy <= 100){


     cout << riadkov[ulohy] << endl; }
     }else{
     cout << "minimalne 1 uloha, maximalne 100 uloh!" << endl;

     }
system("pause");   
}
```

Comment: You cannot create functions inside another functions. Move it outside main function

Comment: Please provide a SSCCE(http://sscce.org/). Your code did not pass any compiler.

Comment: thanks, but now it says that char dlzka_r[100]; shadows a parameter....how can i limit it??

Comment: You see different code? We don't.

Answer (score 1):

As Alex says you cannot create a function inside another, You should make riadkov a lambda function :

```
auto riadkov = [](int arg[], in dkzka_r) -> void {
    // implementation
}
```

Secondly since you try to create dynamically a number of rows what you need is a :

```
char **data; // but you 'll have to malloc/new yourself
```

If you are not required to use char, you can choose a container of strings

EDIT:

compile and run this example (as for char ** ... rtfm)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> data; // contains a sequence of strings
    std::size_t num(0); // number of rows
    do 
    {
        std::cout << "Enter number (1 to 100) of rows : " ;
        std::cin >> num;
    } while (num < 1 || num > 100); 

    for (std::size_t i(0); i < num; ++i)
    {
        data.push_back(std::string()); // add an empty string
        std::cout << "\nEnter data for row " << i << " : ";
        std::cin >> data.back(); // fill the empty string with user input
        if (data.back().length() > 100) {
            std::cout << "Only 1 to 100 characters are allowed";
            data.pop_back(); // remove the last string
            --i; // the ith row will be prosessed again
        }
    }

    // now to print what you inserted in the vector
    std::cout << "Printing contents of the vector\n";
    for (std::size_t i(0), ie(data.size()); i < ie; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << i << ". :" << data[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: and also, if user writes 101 (number of rows to create) it should tell him oops, max is 100! ...so I need a function in another function..